# jquery prevent parent click child function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got this problem if i click on my image div the payoutArticle() function gets also called. I checked several threads on stackoverflow, but none worked

```
<div class="articlepayout" onclick="payoutArticle();">
    <div class="img" > 
          <a href="myurl" rel="shadowbox[photos]">
              <img src="imageurl"/>
          </a>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".articlepayout").click(function(e){ 
        var senderElement = e.target;
        if(senderElement == this) { 
            //what to do here?
        } else { 
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why do you used inline and jquery functions for the same element?

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()` to break bubbling of event.

Comment: @Pekka, I guess it's a typo !

Comment: @RayonDabre i seldom use that one so had typo error there.anyways you have the correct answer.thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use event.stopPropagation() to break bubbling of event.

Refer this example:

```js
 $('.img').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('Img clicked!');
 });
 $('.articlepayout').on('click', function() {
   alert('articlepayout clicked!');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="articlepayout">
  <div class="img">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="shadowbox[photos]">
      <img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <br/>Outside Img
  <br/>Outside Img
  <br/>Outside Img
  <br/>Outside Img
  <br/>Outside Img
</div>
```

Comment: e.stopPropagation(); on img div is enough to prevent it! thank you

Answer (score 0):

The click event handler is registered twice:

- by the onclick attribute
- with the `$(...).click(...)`

In both handler functions the events starts bubbling up on click separateley.
You could remove the `onclick` attribute to prevent the function `payoutArticle` to be called:

```
$(".articlepayout").attr("onclick", "");
```